# Creating a set of buttons with oncick events on them

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have an array of objects in my game, and I want to create buttons in the UI, based on object count in array. In menu construction script, array is scanned for objects, and for each of them button is created, and labeled by object name.

Now I want to do onclick event for these buttons which will display info about respective object in the UI. So I need to somehow create a onclick event for each of appearing buttons, or create universal onclick event for this group of buttons, which will read object name from button and search for that in the array. Is it possible to create events for objects which are going to appear during game? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround - by onclick event get buttons array and find which is hovered by mouse ATM

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could make a widget object containig the button with the onclick event, then in the contruction script you create the widgets.
Here you can find some documentation for widgets:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UMG/UserGuide/WidgetBlueprints/index.html
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/UMG/UserGuide/CreatingWidgets/index.html

Comment: The problem is, I need to refer to certain button in event, and I cannot bind parametrized function to onclick event of newly created buttons. So every button calls same function, which dont know what exactly button called it. Though, I already found workaround to it, thank you.